# How to determine parent object from reference to a property

Tags: javascript, object, properties

```
var object = {foo: 'bar'};
```

Does JavaScript have a way to determine that `object.foo` is a property of `object` from inside a function to which `object.foo` is passed? In other words, is it possible to write a func that could do this:

```
getSource(object.foo) === object
```

Comment: Why don't you explain what you want to achieve, perhaps you are going about it in a too complicated manner

Comment: @mplungjan I want to achieve many things.

Comment: @mplungjan I could pass `object` itself to a function—I want to know if it's possible to get that information without doing that.

Comment: http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2007/01/javascript-getclass-and-isa-functions.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no back-reference like that in JavaScript. What gets passed into a function is a value -- `5`, `"foo"`, an object reference, etc. There's no information on that value that tells you the value came from an object property, much less *which* object's property.

Comment: Thanks, yea I was pretty sure it was impossible—although you must admit it would be cool if there was a mechanism for that.

Comment: @ryanve: :-) It would markedly complicate the underlying engine.

Answer (score 2):

For variables, Javascript uses "pass by value", in other words, when `object.foo` gets passed to any function, what the function will receive is `'bar'`, not a reference to `object.foo`:

```
var object = {foo: 'bar'};
function by_value(v) {
    v = v + v
}
document.write(by_value(object.foo)) // Writes 'bar'
```

In other words, once you have passed `object.foo` to any function, there's no way to know that this comes from `object`

However, if you pass an object, the *value* of that variable will be a *reference* to that object: *(Note: this is not true "pass by reference", see @t-j-crowder's comment):*

```
function as_reference(o) {
    o.foo = o.foo + o.foo
}
document.write(by_reference(object)) // Writes 'barbar'
```

Meaning as a cheap work-around, you can store a "reference" to your object in the object as well:

```
var object = {foo: 'bar'};
object.foo = {val: object.foo, parent: object}
function do_something(v) {
    console.log(v.val);   // foo
    console.log(v.parent) // object
}
do_something(object.foo)
```

Helpful?

Comment: *"However, for objects Javscript uses "call by reference":"* **No**. This is incorrect. JavaScript is *always* pass-by-value. The value that gets passed may be an object reference, but it's still passed *by value*. It's important not to perpetuate this misleading myth. Consider: `function foo(o) { o = null; }` `var obj = {};` `foo(obj);` What's the value of `obj`? If JavaScript used pass-by-reference for objects, `obj` would be `null`. It isn't. The word "reference" in pass-by-reference refers to a reference *to the variable passed*; it has nothing to do with object references.

Comment: Sorry, replied to your comment before saving the edit - curse you, tabbed browsing. Edits should be live now.

Comment: @ Manuel: since `var` is a keyword, it can't be used as a property name using dotted notation (e.g., `v.var`). I changed it to `val` for you. Also **strongly** recommend not relying on the horror that is automatic semicolon insertion.